# If string equals item from list a, followed by item from list b

Tags: python

I'd like to make an if statement to detect if a string could be formed with items from lists, in order. For example, if I want to check if a term had the same meaning as "HelloWorld", I'd have a "hello" list with `['hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Greetings', 'Hola']`, and a "world" list with `['world', 'World', 'Planet', 'Earth']`. Then, check if a string is equal to any item from the "hello" list, directly followed by any item from the "world" list. "HelloWorld", "GreetingsEarth", and "HiPlanet" would all successfully trip the if statement. How would I do this? I'd like to use Python lists, so regex (a|b) seems impractical.

Comment: Are you interested in determining which match was triggered (ie that the Xth item from the hello list was followed by the Yth item from the world list?) or just that there is any match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid a regular expression, you can use a generator expression that tests each combination (generated via `itertools.product`):

```
import itertools
combinations = (''.join((first, second)) for first, second in itertools.product(a, b))
any('HelloWorld' == combination for combination in combinations)
```

Note that this is *far* slower than the regular expression approach, especially when hitting the worst-case scenario (no match):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('search("HelloWorld"); search("HiThere")', 'from __main__ import reMatch as search')
1.8922290802001953
>>> timeit.timeit('search("HelloWorld"); search("HiThere")', 'from __main__ import genMatch as search')
18.3697190284729
```

The generator expression is 10 times slower than the regular expression approach.

(I used a `re.compile()` compiled regular expression for the test).

Comment: Out of curiosity was the re version you tried a compiled re, or was it just a raw `re.match("someregularexpression...")`?  If it wasn't compiled, then feeding it through `re.compile` will likely make it even faster.

Comment: @AdamParkin: Sorry, yes, I used a compiled re. Note that `re.match` still compiles the expression, and uses a cache for that; the slowdown you see is the cache-lookup vs. using the compiled expression directly.

Answer (score 2):

Regexes will work just fine:

```
a = ['hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Greetings', 'Hola']
b = ['world', 'World', 'Planet', 'Earth']

import re
r = '^(%s)(%s)$' % ('|'.join(a), '|'.join(b))

print re.match(r, "HelloWorld").groups() # ('Hello', 'World')
print re.match(r, "HiThere") # None
```

A non-regex solution is tedious:

```
s = "GreetingsEarth"
for x in a:
    if s.startswith(x) and s[len(x):] in b:
        print x, '+', s[len(x):]
        break
```

Comment: Guess the regex method is faster, but by how much?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Regex are really slow.

Comment: The regular expression is doing basically the same thing as the Python code. On the other hand, the regex engine is in C. I think it probably partly depends on the lengths of the lists.

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on a number of factors.  Depending on the circumstances a re can actually be quite faster, especially if you compile the regex in advance with `re.compile`.  A compiled re is O(1) (constant) time, whereas a loop version is going to depend on the size of the input.

Comment: @AdamParkin: re compilation is not an issue, because every regex gets compiled exactly once (re module maintains a cache of compiled patterns).

Comment: That's true, though potentially misleading, if one is using the same re many times in a program, and is using many different re's then it makes sense to compile it in advance & save the reference, else you run the risk of having it get dropped from the re module's cache & end up being recompiled.   See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#re.compile): "The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to re.match(), re.search() or re.compile() are cached, so _programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time_ needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

This actually could be done with a regular expression, like so:

```
list1 = ['hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Greetings', 'Hola']
list2 = ['world', 'World', 'Planet', 'Earth']
regex = "(%s)(%s)" % ("|".join(list1), "|".join(list2))
print re.match(regex, "HelloWorld")
```

But it could also be done with `itertools.product`:

```
print any("HelloWorld" == x + y for x, y in itertools.product(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a set for the second list so that you don't have to iterate every time over all it's items.

```
a = ['hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Greetings', 'Hola']
b = ['world', 'World', 'Planet', 'Earth']

b_set = set(b)
needle = 'HelloWorld'
for start in a:
    if needle.startswith(start) and needle[len(start):] in b_set:
         print 'match'
```

If you are looking for a shorter version

```
any((needle[len(start):] in b_set for start in a if needle.startswith(start)))
```

In contrast to the `itertools.product` this solution does not have to compare all `n^2` possible combinations, but has just to walk once over the first list (`n`) and in worst case do an additional set lookup.